# VBScript not reading path greater than 260 Characters

Tags: vbscript

Im supposed to write a script that is given a starting folder and loops through all the folders and files and if it comes across a path that is greater then 250, it writes it into a text file. It works but if the path is greater than 259 characters, it will not write the path into the text file. Is there an easy fix to this. My script is on the bottom.  Thank you

```
Const ForWriting = 2
dim x
StartFolder = "C:\Users\Sample\Desktop\Notess\Reports"
LogFile = "C:\Users\Sample\Desktop\rand.txt"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objLogFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(LogFile, ForWriting, True)
Call CheckFolder(StartFolder)

Set objFSO = Nothing
objLogFile.Close

Sub CheckFolder(Folder)
    Set ArrFiles = objFSO.GetFolder(Folder).Files
    For Each File In ArrFiles

x=len(file)
        IF X > 250 THEN objLogFile.WriteLine (File & ", "& X)


    Next

    Set ArrSubFolders = objFSO.GetFolder(Folder).SubFolders
    For Each SubFolder In ArrSubFolders
        call CheckFolder(SubFolder)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely a limitation due to the MAX_PATH variable in Windows. While NTFS allows paths up to 32000 characters, Windows has this lovely variable that is used by many API's which is set to 256.

My guess is that FSO, being as ancient as it is, doesn't handle file paths that are greater than 259 as a result (256 characters plus the three characters from "C:\")

[Check out this post over at the excellent blog.codinghorror.com](http://blog.codinghorror.com/filesystem-paths-how-long-is-too-long/)

Comment: Yes, it's a limitation inflicted by the Win32 API. The only workable way around this for VBScript that I've found so far is to shorten the path by mapping the parent folder to a drive letter via `subst` and continue from that drive.